# Is it possible to skip a column when running a query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am running a query that is returning multiple rows for a column ID because the column ID has two distinct values in another column (Type) (please see below).

Is it possible to skip the 'Type' column that has two values when running the query to avoid duplication of ID's? I do not need this column and it is affecting my query results.

My current output (excluding the 'Type' column, just added for clarification)

```
+----+-------+----------+
| ID | State |   Type   |  
+----+-------+----------+
|  1 | GA    | Building |  
|  1 | GA    | Outdoor  |  
|  2 | GA    | Outdoor  |  
|  3 | GA    | Building |  
+----+-------+----------+
```

The output I should be getting

```
+----+-------+
| ID | State |   
+----+-------+
|  1 | GA    |  
|  2 | GA    | 
|  3 | GA    |
+----+-------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, use

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ID, State ...
```

Comment: Hi @Vasya, it's a pretty long query which already has the distinct value applied. This is not sorting the issue. I have also tried creating temp tables and only pulling the columns that I need, but it is still factoring in the two distinct Type values. I should have also mentioned, that the above is left joining onto the main table that I am using.

Comment: @Codash: post the full query, otherwise we are just guessing what the problem is

Comment: @Codash Are you looking for a subquery here?  Like you've already got one query that does most of the work, and then you want to select from that query to only get some of the columns?  Something like `SELECT ID, STATE FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID, STATE ...);`?